# Get the name field in user table

Tags: php, laravel, calendar

I need to get the name field of the users table that is integrated in the tasks table.

The complete method

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $tasks = [];
    $task = Task::all();
    if($task->count()) {
        foreach ($task as $key => $value) {
            $tasks[] = Calendar::event(
                $value->user_id,
                true,
                new \DateTime($value->start_date),
                new \DateTime($value->end_date.' +1 day'),
                null,
                // Add color and link on event
                [
                    'color' => '#f05050',
                ]
            );
        }
    }
    $calendar = Calendar::addEvents($tasks);

    $user_id  = $request->get('user_id');
    $title  = $request->get('title');

    $list = Task::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->user_id($user_id)
        ->title($title)
        ->paginate(20);
    $users = User::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->pluck('name', 'id');
    return view('tasks.index', compact('calendar', 'task', 'list', 'users'));
}
```

this section passes the parameter to the calendar

```
$value->user_id,
```

this is the view:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if there is a relation between task and user you can add relation in task model called
user

```
   function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
```

and then use it

```
      $value->user->name;
```